# What does %d mean? Why d and not another letter?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

I'm just starting out learning C and wanted to ask some very elementary questions. I don't have any programming background at all. I'm just at the very start of a tutorial (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) and there's some things it doesn't explain. Like, for example, in this following introductory simple program…

Question: why does he use "%d" – why d and not another letter? I understand the % is the modulo operand, meaning remainder, but why d? I understand that stdio.h imports a library/glossary of terms to use, such as printf and so on… is %d the same as that? :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int this_is_a_number;

    printf( "Please enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &this_is_a_number );
    printf( "You entered %d", this_is_a_number );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happened to reading the documentation for the functions you're calling?

Comment: d in %d stands for decimal. You should read about printf format strings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

OR in short RTFM!

Comment: I recommend you revise the way you learn. It's no good coming running to StackOverflow for every minute detail of the language fundamentals. You won't get the best learning experience, and you won't get the best out of StackOverflow. Instead, pick up a good C textbook (we have recommendations in the FAQ) and learn to use language references (such as `man`). Then work yourself through as many problems as you can, and make simple test cases to gain confidence and understanding of each individual component.

Comment: @RBK: "Read the Formatted-IO Manual"?

Comment: "This question does not show _any_ research effort" - to explain the slew of downvotes.

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, not really.. I intended(& took it for granted) that for a beginner the K&R book is the manual(or Bible). They are the C Gods you see :)

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why does %d stand for Integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13409014/187543)

Comment: -10  votes! you dont need to show your ass to new users like this, I am sure he will not be back again. be more constructive!

Answer (score 5):

Actually `%` is not the modulo operand or modulo operator here because it's included inside a string. It's just a character chosen to separate literal text from parameters. And `d` is used because it performs input and output in **d**ecimal (base 10).

Comment: actually, `%` _is_ the modulo operator at times (didn't downvote).

Comment: @JanDvorak: He didn't say "operator", he said "operand". Although that sounds Kafkaesque, it's not wrong :-S

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Mat: the tutorial is very basic/brief so it omits a lot. I've got the C book by Denis Ritchie, which I'll tackle next. @RBK: Thanks. Helpful. Kerrek SB: I have been trying to get my head around programming for almost a year, reading a range of material, but I just can't pick it up. I'm not a genius, but I'm not stupid either. I tried to avoid coming to Stack Overflow with elementary questions. I'm from a journalistic background and my attitude is to explain things in a very basic way. I do not see that in computer programming books/tutorials at all. Thanks.

Comment: I meant Dennis M. Ritchie. And Brian W. Kernighan. I'm nervous.

Answer (score 1):

In this case is not a modulo operator but a sign meaning you want to display the sub-sequent information in a certain format. The letter is called a *specifier*.

`%d` means you're going to display it as a decimal integer. `%f` would display it as a float number etc.

More in the *man* : http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf