# Should I use %i or %d to print an integer in C using printf()?

Tags: c, console, integer, printf

I am just learning C and I have a little knowledge of Objective-C due to dabbling in iOS development. In Objective-C, I was using `NSLog(@"%i", x);` to print the variable *x* to the console. However, I have been reading a few C tutorials and they are saying to use `%d` instead of `%i`.

`printf("%d", x);`
and `printf("%i", x);` both print *x* to the console correctly.

These both seem to get me to the same place, so which is preferred? Is one more semantically correct or is *right*?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

They are completely equivalent when used with `printf()`. Personally, I prefer `%d`. It's used more often (should I say "it's the idiomatic conversion specifier for `int`"?).

(One difference between `%i` and `%d` is that when used with `scanf()`, then `%d` always expects a decimal integer, whereas `%i` recognizes the `0` and `0x` prefixes as octal and hexadecimal, but no sane programmer uses `scanf()` anyway, so this should not be a concern.)

Comment: Thanks :) So more just a developer's preference?

Comment: @HenryHarris Yes, but if you take my advice, you use `%d` ;)

Comment: This may be extremely late, but what is wrong with using scanf()?

Comment: @Spellbinder2050, see [http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Basically, scanf() does not respond well to unexpected input.

Comment: Did you check out the link Chad provided? `"It's nearly impossible to deal gracefully with all of these potential problems when using scanf; it's far easier to read entire lines (with fgets or the like),...(Functions like strtol, strtok, and atoi are often useful"`. Man, I hate these kind of comments where people say _"Oh, everyone else is shitty"_, but don't read through the resources provided, just like OiciTrap.

Answer (score 25):

I am just adding an example here, because I think examples make it easier to understand.

In printf(), they behave identically, so you can use any either %d or %i. But they behave differently in scanf().

For example:

```
int main()
{
    int num, num2;
    scanf("%d%i", &num, &num2); // Reading num using %d and num2 using %i

    printf("%d\t%d", num, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can see the different results for identical inputs.

**`num`**:

We are reading `num` using `%d` so when we enter `010` it ignores the first `0` and treats it as decimal `10`.

**`num2`**:

We are reading `num2` using `%i`.

That means it will treat decimals, octals, and hexadecimals differently.

When it give `num2` `010` it sees the leading `0` and parses it as octal.

When we print it using `%d` it prints the decimal equivalent of octal `010` which is `8`.

Comment: Upvoting you, but I'd have preferred to see a complete answer rather than patchwork over another answer (which is exactly what the StackOverflow project is fighting against)

Answer (score 4):

The `d` and `i` conversion specifiers behave the same with `fprintf`, but they behave differently for `fscanf`.

As some other wrote in their answer, the idiomatic way to print an `int` is using `d` conversion specifier.

Regarding `i` specifier and `fprintf`, *[C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) Rationale* says that:

> The %i conversion specifier was added in C89 for programmer convenience to provide
> symmetry with fscanf’s %i conversion specifier, even though it has exactly the same meaning
> as the %d conversion specifier when used with fprintf.

Answer (score 2):

Both `%d` and `%i` can be used to print an integer.

%d stands for "decimal", and %i for "integer." You can use %x to print in hexadecimal, and %o to print in octal.

You can use %i as a synonym for %d, if you prefer to indicate "integer" instead of "decimal."

On input, using scanf(), you can use use both %i and %d as well. %i means parse it as an integer in any base (octal, hexadecimal, or decimal, as indicated by a 0 or 0x prefix), while %d means parse it as a decimal integer.

Check here for more explanation:

*[Why does %d stand for Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409014/why-does-d-stand-for-integer)*

Answer (score 1):

%d seems to be the norm for printing integers, I never figured out why, they behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, they produce identical output on printf, but behave differently on scanf.  I would prefer `%d` over `%i` for this reason.  A number that is printed with `%d` can be read in with `%d` and you will get the same number.  That is not always true with `%i`, if you ever choose to use zero padding.  Because it is common to copy printf format strings into scanf format strings, I would avoid `%i`, since it could give you a surprising bug introduction:

I write `fprintf("%i ...", ...);`

You copy and write `fscanf(%i ...", ...);`

I decide I want to align columns more nicely and make alphabetization behave the same as sorting:  `fprintf("%03i ...", ...);` (or `%04d`)

Now when you read my numbers, anything between 10 and 99 is interpreted in octal.  Oops.

If you want decimal formatting, just say so.