# Creating a Simple Commissions Calculator with Java

Tags: java

I am creating a simple commissions calculator, whereas, one can input the final sales price of an infinite amount of sales; then at the end it prints out the total amount of the commission plus a base pay rate ($200).

Here is my initial code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentsModule2_Program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Intialization Phase
        double sold = 0;
        double soldCounter = 0;

        double baseRate = 200.00;
        double commissionRate = 0.09;

        System.out.print("Enter total of sold item or -1 if done: ");
        int value = input.nextInt();

        while (sold != -1)
        {
            sold = sold + value;
            soldCounter = soldCounter + 1;

            System.out.print("Enter price of sold item or -1 if done: ");
            value = input.nextInt();
        } 

        double totalCommission = sold * commissionRate + baseRate;
        System.out.printf("%nTotal pay for the week is: %d%n", sold);

    }

}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the program an error code appears.

Here is the error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at     assignmentsmodule2_program2.AssignmentsModule2_Program2.main(AssignmentsModule2_Program2.java:31)
Java Result: 1
```

Is there anyone out there who can lend some help?

Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 31 as indicated by the exception message: `AssignmentsModule2_Program2.java:31`?

Comment: Since you're requesting integers from the user, what do you write into the console?

Comment: `"that is the UNC"`? -- Please translate. The exception stack trace is telling you exactly what line is throwing the exception, and all I'm asking is that you indicate the line for us. Again, **which line is line 31**?

Comment: Universal naming convention - where the file is located in my computer

Comment: @justLearning He is asking which line of your *AssignmentsModule2_Program2.java* file is line *31*. So which of your `input.nextInt();` calls is line *31*? (but that doesn't matter much :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program is expecting an integer as input. The exception is thrown when a float or a char is used as input. I would use `double` variable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentsModule2_Program2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Intialization Phase
    double sold = 0.0;
    int soldCounter = 0;

    double baseRate = 200.00;
    double commissionRate = 0.09;

    System.out.print("Enter total of sold item or -1 if done: ");
    double value = input.nextDouble();

    while (value > 0)
    {
        sold = sold + value;
        soldCounter = soldCounter + 1;

        System.out.print("Enter price of sold item or -1 if done: ");
        value = input.nextDouble();
    } 

    double totalCommission = sold * commissionRate + baseRate;
    System.out.printf("%nTotal pay for the week is: %f%n", sold);

  }

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at assignmentsmodule2_program2.AssignmentsModule2_Program2.main(AssignmentsModule2_Program2.java:43)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Indeed, I changed in the code also the `%d` you used in your `printf` statement with a `%f`.

Comment: @justLearning Look what you can find with a small amound of research effort: [Problem with System.out.printf command in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3693079)

Comment: Thanks guys...I appreciate your help. This worked perfectly. I wasn't thinking correctly about the conversions.